# Laplace of a composition of 2 functions

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

Is there a formula for the Laplace of the composition of 2 functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ ? Namely, what is Laplace$[f(g(t))]$ ?

Thanks

Comment: No particular identities come to mind for me. I guess most of the time people just computer $f(g(t))$ and apply the Laplace transform to it as they would any other function (i.e. using the other identities).

Comment: Yes this is right but in my case $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are general